# How to resolve coq suffix import error (physical path bound to logical path)

Tags: emacs, coq, proof-general

Probably a coq newbie question, but I could not find a ready solution so I'll ask here for reference. The cocq version is `8.5pl2`

I tried to build
[coqfj](https://github.com/hephaestus-pl/coqfj). The first `make` attempt has failed with some error in line 37 in `src/FJ/ClassTable.v`. This question is not about that error.

Taking a closer look, I opened `ClassTable.v` in emacs proofgeneral and pressed `C-c C-n`, or alternatively run `coqc src/FJ/ClassTable.v`. The result is an error in line 1:

```
File "./src/FJ/ClassTable.v", line 1, characters 15-23:
Error: Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path matching suffix FJ.
```

It seems the import `require import FJ.Lists` cannot be resolved (although FJ is used as a prefix, not suffix). I've noticed that `make` has already created a compiled file `src/Lists.vo`, that should be picked up by coqc.

How to tell coqc that it should resolve this "suffix" by looking at either the `*.vo` or `*.v` files in the `src` folder?

Comment: `coqc -R src FJ src/FJ/ClassTable.v` should work.

Comment: good. how to make it stick in pg?

Comment: Hmmm, I tried opening `ClassTable.v` in Emacs and it just works (I mean the imports work)! I have Emacs 25.1 with the latest PG and [company-coq](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/company-coq) on top of it.

Comment: Do you have `_CoqProject` file in the project root directory with `-R src FJ` in its first line? It should be there if you didn't (accidentally) delete/modify it. My guess is that PG uses that file.

Comment: It works now after reinstalling PG from instructions here https://github.com/ProofGeneral/PG

Comment: did you manage to fix this?